# Как правильно определить границы прокрутки в окне с кнопками?

Tags: c++, winapi

Допустим создаю 200 кнопок (BUTTONCOUNT = 200), пытаюсь учесть границы скроллинга с учетом высоты и количества кнопок, но не выходит. Есть ли способ не хардкодить под определенное количество кнопок каждый раз?

```
case WM_CREATE:
{
    int x, y;
    int ypos = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i<BUTTONCOUNT; i++)
    {
        char strBtn[500] = "Number: ";
        char buffer[500];
        itoa(i, buffer, 10);
        strcat_s(strBtn, buffer);

        CreateWindow(
            "BUTTON",  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed 
            strBtn,      // Button text 
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Styles 
            10,         // x position 
            ypos,         // y position 
            120,        // Button width
            30,        // Button height
            handleforwindow,     // Parent window
            NULL,       // No menu.
            (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(handleforwindow, GWL_HINSTANCE),
            NULL);


        CreateWindow(
            "BUTTON",  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed 
            strBtn,      // Button text 
            WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,  // Styles 
            160,         // x position 
            ypos,         // y position 
            110,        // Button width
            30,        // Button height
            handleforwindow,     // Parent window
            NULL,       // No menu.
            (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(handleforwindow, GWL_HINSTANCE),
            NULL);

        ypos += 32;

    }



    SetScrollRange(handleforwindow, SB_VERT, 0, 30*200, FALSE);


    return 0;

}



case WM_VSCROLL:
{
    SCROLLINFO vscr;
    vscr.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
    vscr.fMask = SIF_ALL;

    GetScrollInfo(handleforwindow, SB_VERT, &vscr);

    int min = vscr.nMin;
    int max = vscr.nMax;
    int ncurPos = vscr.nPos;
    int fpos = ncurPos;

    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(handleforwindow, &rect);


    switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
    case SB_THUMBTRACK:
    {
        ncurPos = vscr.nTrackPos;
        break;
    }
    case SB_LINEUP:
    {
        if (ncurPos > min + 200)
            ncurPos -= 200;
        else
            ncurPos = min;
        break;
    }
    case SB_LINEDOWN:
    {
        if (ncurPos < max - 200)
        {
            ncurPos += 200;
        }
        else
        {
            ncurPos = max;
        }
        break;
    }
    case SB_PAGEUP:
    {
        if (ncurPos > min)
        {
            ncurPos -= 400;
        }
        else ncurPos = min;
    }
    case SB_PAGEDOWN:
    {
        if (ncurPos < (max - 200))
        {
            ncurPos += 200;
        }
        else
        {
            ncurPos = max;
        }
    }
    }


    SetScrollPos(handleforwindow, SB_VERT, ncurPos, TRUE);
    ScrollWindow(handleforwindow, 0, (fpos - ncurPos), NULL, NULL);


    break;
}
```

Comment: Зачем в окне 200 кнопок? Что значит "не выходит"?

Comment: задание такое, а не выходит - либо не хватает границы скролла, либо после последней кнопки рстается место пустое

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал `ypos` глобальной, чтобы высота прокручиваемой области была видна в других обработчиках; добавил к `ypos` 8 после цикла (для симметрии); убрал `SetScrollRange` из `WM_CREATE`; и добавил обработчик `WM_SIZE`:

```
case WM_SIZE:{
    int oldPos = GetScrollPos(hWnd, SB_VERT);
    SetScrollRange(hWnd, SB_VERT, 0, ypos - (short)HIWORD(lParam), FALSE);
    int newPos = GetScrollPos(hWnd, SB_VERT);
    ScrollWindow(hWnd, 0, oldPos - newPos, NULL, NULL);
    break;
}
```

В качестве `handleforwindow` я использовал основное окно(`hWnd`), так что, если вы используете другой контейнер - выставляйте `SetScrollRange`, когда его высота меняется.

Обратите особое внимание, что в 4й параметр `SetScrollRange` передается высота прокручиваемой области, т.е. **высоту самого контейнера из нее надо вычесть**, она же не прокручивается. В моем случае высота контейнера приходит в `HIWORD(lParam)`.

---

[Архив с проектом](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pik6fthqudsliq5/so-752383.zip?dl=0)
[Готовый exe (x86)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uzqw1q4jvk64801/so-752383.exe?dl=0)

---

Live demo:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]